# How can I reference images online in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have something like this:

`<img class="product_image" src="{{ product.Image_url }}">`

`product.Image_url` is referenced to my database that has an image URL like `https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*YNBTPaCNBNWLoT7XAbJ1Lw.png`. This piece of code is giving me a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Would appreciate help in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: need more details. Currently  I can say  that your path to image is wrong

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr The image path was just an example. Updated it now, thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arsalanakhtarsays/j1yhwbc4/

try this hope you get the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the image `https://something.com/something.png` is really present (paste the url to browsers address bar to be sure you can load the asset) then try this:

```
<img class="product_image" :src="product.Image_url">
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to :D

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use the markup you currently have, vue will log a warning into the JS console explaining what's wrong and how to fix it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: { Image_url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png?text=Product+image' }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img class="product_image" src="{{ product.Image_url }}">
</div>
```

Specifically, running the snippet above will produce the following warning:

> `src="{{ product.Image_url }}"`: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`, use `<div :id="val">`.

To fix it, just do what it says, i.e. replace `src="{{ product.Image_url }}"` with `:src="product.Image_url"`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: { Image_url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png?text=Product+image' }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img class="product_image" :src="product.Image_url">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="product_image" :src="product.Image_url">
```

Just bind it with a colon and remove the brackets.